# How to solve system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I would like to solve a system of differential equations
\begin{align*}
&x''(t) = -a_0(a_1 - bz'(t))\cos(wt), &&x(t_o)= 0,  &&x'(t_o)=0\\
&z''(t)= -a_0 bx'(t)\cos(wt), &&z(t_o) =0,  &&z'(t_o)= 0
\end{align*}
It reduces to a third order equation

$z'''(t) = a(1-cz'(t))\cos^2(wt)-\tan(wt) dz''(t), z(t_o)=0,z'(t_o)= 0$

I tried mathematica and matlab but they do not want to return analytical solution.

This is free electron in electromagnetic field.
If the field is complex mathematica find some solution. But the answer is also complex. Is it possible to get real Z for cos(wt) field out of it.

```
eqns = {z'''[t] == a*Exp[I*t*2*w]*(1 - z'[t]*c) + z''[t]*(I*w), 
   z[t0] == 0, z'[t0] == 0};

soln = Real[DSolve[eqns, z, t][[1]]]
```

Comment: convert it into first order differential equation

Comment: A more sensible way to space things in mathjax is to use the `align` environment coming from amslatex. Google should provide lots of tutorials.

Comment: edited @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: is it from some book?@anonymous

Comment: This is the lorentz force for the motion of free electron in plane wave. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267217/free-electron-in-plane-wave-electromagnetic-field-does-the-motion-have-analytic?noredirect=1#comment594199_267217

Answer (score 2):

$$x''(t) = -a_0(a_1 - bz'(t))\cos(wt),\ \ \ \  x(t_o)= 0,\ \ \ \ \  x'(t_o)=0$$
let $x'(t)=y(t) ,z'(t)=\beta(t)$
than we get 
$$y'(t)=-a_0(a_1 - b\beta(t))\cos(wt)$$

the second equation converts to $$\beta'(t)= -a_0b y(t)\cos(wt) $$
i think it can be solved now
on solving and referring results from work of @okrzysik [Solution of a system of linear odes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853974/how-to-solve-solve-a-pair-of-coupled-linear-odes/1854051#1854051)

$$\beta(t) = A \cos\left(\frac{c \sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\right) + B \sin\left(\frac{c \sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\right) + \frac{d}{c^2} $$
and

$$y'(t)=(-a_0a_1\cos(wt)+a_0b A \cos\left(\frac{c \sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\right) \cos(wt)+ a_0Bb \sin\left(\frac{c \sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)\cos(wt) +a_0 \frac{bd}{c^2}\cos(wt))$$
on integrating

---

$$y(t)=\frac{1}{w}(a_0 \frac{bd}{c^2}-a_0a_1)\sin(wt)+a_0bA\frac{w^2}{c}\sin(\frac{c\sin(wt)}{w})-a_0Bb\frac{w^2}{c}\cos(\frac{c\sin(wt)}{w})+K$$

---

now $z(t),x(t)$ could be calculated from $\beta(t),y(t)$

---

$$z(t) = A \int \cos\left(\frac{c \sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\right) dt+ B \int\sin\left(\frac{c \sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)dt +\int \frac{d}{c^2} dt$$

Comment: Thanks. It is still difficult.

Comment: @Anonymous you might find the solution that I've just found to this problem useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853974/how-to-solve-this-system-of-coupled-non-linear-equations/1854051#1854051.

Comment: Thanks. The integral is complicated z'(t)~cos(a(sin(t))). Matlab is giving similar expression for z=(E*(t - int(cos((B*a0*(sin(w*to + w*t) - sin(to*t)))/w), t, to, t)))/B